# simple function isn't calling the callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
const five = function() {
  console.log(5)
}

const func = function(callback) {
  console.log(3)
  callback
  console.log(7)
}

func(five)
```

I would like to know why I have in the output

```
3
7
```

instead of

```
3
5
7
```

I tried to put callback() with parentheses and I got an error, why?

Comment: What error did you have when you tried to call the callback? The obvious answer to why the callback isn't getting called is: you don't call the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the function is assigned to a variable you need to call it as a function, with parentheses.

```js
const five = function() {
  console.log(5)
}

const func = function(callback) {
  console.log(3)
  callback()
  console.log(7)
}

func(five)
```

Comment: Allegedely they _already_ _"tried to put callback() with parentheses"_.

Comment: Apparently not like this. What's your point?

Comment: My point is that it's unclear what exactly they tried, which is why I asked for more detail, hence it's unclear whether this solves their problem. Frankly it seems very unlikely the outcome will be valuable content at all - if this _does_ fix it the question should be binned as trivial.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is that you aren't calling `callback` with parentheses.

To invoke a function in JavaScript, you need to use parentheses at the end, even if you don't need to pass in any parameters.

So, change your `callback` line from this:

```js
callback;
```

To this:

```js
callback();
```

---

In summary, this is the fully working code.

```js
const five = function() {
  console.log(5);
}

const func = function(callback) {
  console.log(3);
  callback(); // This line has been modified
  console.log(7);
}

func(five); // Should output: 3, 5, 7
```